# Selecting all records using SQL LIMIT and OFFSET query

Tags: mysql, sql, database, postgresql, sqlite

I wonder if there is a way to accomplish:

```
SELECT * FROM table
```

by using `LIMIT` and `OFFSET` like so:

```
SELECT * FROM table LIMIT all OFFSET 0
```

Can I write SQL statement **using** LIMIT and OFFSET but still getting ALL results?

* *Of course, I can use an `IF` statement, but I would rather avoid it if possible*

Comment: why do you want to write a LIMIT if you dont' want the query results to be limited? The whole purpose of LIMIT is (duh) to LIMIT the number of results.

Comment: Very simple: sometimes you want to write only one line of code (or the min lines required) that will cover ALL different scenarios.

Comment: Example: A script that takes an argument as the value of limit for a SQL query. Sometimes you want to run it for 5, sometimes for 50, sometimes for all.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

From the [MySQL documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html):

> To retrieve all rows from a certain offset up to the end of the result
>   set, you can use some large number for the second parameter. This
>   statement retrieves all rows from the 96th row to the last:
>
> SELECT * FROM tbl LIMIT 95,18446744073709551615;

So getting all rows might look as follows:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl LIMIT 0,18446744073709551615;
```

Comment: "some large number" - MySQL... terrible

Comment: 18446744073709551615 isn't just some number though; it's the max value of a bigint

Comment: Yes I thought it would be something of the sort but they should really say that instead of "some large number"... or no?

Comment: I agree. Something like MAX_INT_NUMBER, which could then change depending on the amount of bits in the system processor in the future.

Comment: PHP will cast a variable containing '18446744073709551615' to type FLOAT, causing the retrieval of only 1 result. Using PHP 7.3.12.

Comment: I guess -1^1 is bit more readable (pun intended)

Answer (score 11):

Yes, it is possible by providing `NULL`:

```
SELECT * FROM tab LIMIT NULL OFFSET NULL
```

**[db<>fiddle PostgreSQL demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=2e60db6973f59924ae91281675c08592)**

> [7.6. LIMIT and OFFSET](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/queries-limit.html)
>
> LIMIT ALL is the same as omitting the LIMIT clause, as is LIMIT with a NULL argument.

---

> **[Snowflake LIMIT / FETCH](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/constructs/limit.html)**
>
> The values **NULL**, **empty string ('')**, and **$$$$** are also accepted and are treated as **“unlimited”**; this is useful primarily for connectors and drivers (such as the JDBC driver) if they receive an incomplete parameter list when dynamically binding parameters to a statement.
>
> ```
> SELECT * FROM demo1 ORDER BY i LIMIT NULL OFFSET NULL;
>
> SELECT * FROM demo1 ORDER BY i LIMIT '' OFFSET '';
>
> SELECT * FROM demo1 ORDER BY i LIMIT $$$$ OFFSET $$$$;
> ```

Comment: Just what I needed, limit null. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

I used this code in nodeJS with MySQL and it's run well, It's may help you.
Why you use it?

1. It's reliable because it's a string that will append with query.
2. If you want to set limit then you can put the limitation with the variable otherwise pass 0 with variable.

   ```
   var noOfGroupShow=0;  //0: all, rest according to number   
   if (noOfGroupShow == 0) {
       noOfGroupShow = '';
   } 
   else {
       noOfGroupShow = ' LIMIT 0, '+noOfGroupShow;
   }
   var sqlGetUser = "SELECT `user_name`,`first_name`,`last_name`,`image`,`latitude`, `longitude`,`phone`,`gender`,`country`,`status_message`,`dob` as user_date_of_birth FROM `tb_user` WHERE `user_id`=?"+noOfGroupShow;
   ```

Answer (score 2):

This may not be the best way to do it, but its the first that comes to mind...

`SELECT * FROM myTable LIMIT 0,1000000`

Replace 1000000 with some adequately large number that you know will always be larger than the total number of records in the table.

Comment: Thx for putting your time.

Comment: This is not a reliable solution.

Comment: One point to want to query all records is you don't know how many records there could be.

Answer (score 2):

As the record will grow up, use `mysql_num_rows` to dynamically find total amount of records, instead of using `some large number`.

```
$cektotalrec=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM TABLE");
$numoffset=mysql_num_rows($cektotalrec); 
$numlimit="0";
```

then:

```
$final="SELECT * FROM table ".$numlimit.", ".$numoffset"";
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe not the cleanest solution but setting limit to a very high number could work. Offset needs to be 0.

Why not use a `IF` statement where you add the limit and offset to the query as a statement is true?

Comment: Of course that is a reasonable approach however my goal was to avoid if by writing one line of code:                                  $this->db->get($database, $limit, $offset)

Answer (score -1):

1. You might receive an error if you set the limit to a very high number as defined by mysql doc. Thereofre, you should try to limit it  9999999999999, going higher can give you an error unless you set up server to go higher.
2. You might want to use LIMIT in a function, therefore it is not a bad idea. If you use it in a function, you might want it to be Limit All at one point and limit 1 at another point.
3. Below, I list an example where you might want your application to have no limit.

function get_navigation($select = "*", $from= "pages", $visible= 1, $subject_id = 2, $order_by = "position", $sort_by = "asc", $offset=0, $limit = 9551615){
    global $connection;

```
$query = " SELECT {$select} ";
$query .= " FROM {$from}  ";

$query .= " WHERE visible = {$visible} ";
$query .= " AND subject_id = {$subject_id} ";

$query .= " ORDER BY {$order_by}  {$sort_by} ";
$query .= " LIMIT {$offset}, {$limit} ";

mysqli_query($connection, $query);
$navigation_set = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
confirm_query($navigation_set);
return $navigation_set;


}

define ("SELECT", "*");
define ("FROM", "pages");
define ("VISIBLE", 1);
define ("SUBJECT_ID", 3);
define ("ORDER_BY", "position");
define ("SORT_BY", "ASC");
define ("LIMIT", "0");


$navigation_set = get_navigation(SELECT, FROM, VISIBLE, SUBJECT_ID, ORDER_BY, SORT_BY);
```

Comment: wow why would you use defines instead variables in code like this, its crazy