# SQL, how to pick portion of list of items via SELECT, WHERE clauses?

Tags: sql, where-clause, postgresql-8.4

I'm passing three parameter to URL: `&p1=eventID`, `&p2=firstItem`, `&p3=numberOfItems`. first parameter is a column of table. second parameter is the first item that I'm looking for. Third parameter says pick how many items after `firstItem`.

for example in first query user send `&p1=1`, `&p2=0`, `&p3=20`. Therefore, I need first 20 items of list.
Next time if user sends `&p1=1`, `&p2=21`, `&p3=20`, then I should pass second 20 items (from item 21 to item 41).

PHP file is able to get parameters. currently, I'm using following string to query into database:

```
public function getPlaceList($eventId, $firstItem, $numberOfItems) {
        $records = array();
        $query = "select * from {$this->TB_ACT_PLACES} where eventid={$eventId}";

        ...
}
```

Result is a long list of items. If I add LIMIT 20 at the end of string, then since I'm not using Token then result always is same.

how to change the query in a way that meets my requirement?
any suggestion would be appreciated. Thanks

=> **update:**
I can get the whole list of items and then select from my first item to last item via `for(;;)` loop. But I want to know is it possible to do similar thing via sql? I guess this way is more efficient way.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11728704/use-limit-to-paginate-results-in-mysql-query

Comment: Thanks, I just looked at but I think that solution is based on pagination that I'm not using it.

Comment: ahh, gotcha, see this link, instructions on using the second argument with the limit keyword.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15950871/select-all-records-using-mysql-limit-and-offset-query

Comment: I think this tends to be database specific.  Please tell us which db and add that tag

Comment: Thanks Sam, I'm using postegreSql as database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my answer here: [stackoverflow.com/a/8242764/513413](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8242764/513413)

For other's reference, I changed my query based on what Joel and above link said:

```
$query = "select places.title, places.summary, places.description, places.year, places.date from places where places.eventid = $eventId order by places.date limit $numberOfItems offset $firstItem";
```

Answer (score 2):

I would construct the final query to be like this:

```
SELECT <column list> /* never use "select *" in production! */
FROM Table
WHERE p1ColumnName >= p2FirstItem
ORDER BY p1ColumnName
LIMIT p3NumberOfItems
```

The `ORDER BY` is important; according to my reading of the [documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/static/queries-limit.html), PostGreSql won't guarantee which rows you get without it. I know Sql Server works much the same way.

Beyond this, I'm not sure how to build this query safely. You'll need to be *very careful* that your method for constructing that sql statement does not leave you vulnerable to sql injection attacks. At first glance, it looks like I could very easily put a malicious value into your column name url parameter.

Comment: +1, Thanks Joel for your valuable information. Although it was not my direct answer, I found it valuable since this is my first attempt to learn SQL. I found my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8242764/513413

Answer (score 0):

If you are using mysql, then use the `LIMIT` keyword.

```
SELECT *
 FROM Table
 LIMIT $firstItem, $numberOfItems
```

See the documentation [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select.html) (search for `LIMIT` in the page).