# OFFSET without LIMIT in mysql

Tags: mysql, limit, offset

Is there any way to use OFFSET without LIMIT in mysql?  I tried many ways and many times.  I also searched a lot.

Comment: Check this [**ANSWER**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15950871/select-all-records-using-mysql-limit-and-offset-query)

Comment: You should ask what you really want to accomplish, rather than trying to bend mysql syntax to your needs. Offset must be used in conjunction with limit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No there is no way. You need to provide the LIMIT.

Then [manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/select.html) says:

> To retrieve all rows from a certain offset up to the end of the result
>   set, you can use some large number for the second parameter.

Comment: Is there any work around query

Comment: @padippist:- You can provide some large number in case you are not sure. Thats what I can think of but I dont think there is any other workaround.