# MySQL bound variable for LIMIT to default to none

Tags: php, mysql

Unless I have specified a limit

```
    $values = [
        ':limit' => $this->limit,
        ':offset' => $this->offset
    ];
```

by setting `$this->limit`, I want this bound to default to no limit

```
const QUERY = "SELECT * FROM Project LIMIT :limit OFFSET :offset";
```

I've tried something like

```
    $values = [
        ':limit' => $this->limit ? $this->limit : null,
        ':offset' => $this->offset
    ];
```

But I wondered if there was a key word in SQL to ignore the limit flag. I.e. `LIMIT ALL` - if that makes sense.

Comment: You should not be solving this using SQL, it's a problem in your application layer, not the db layer. You can use 2 queries, one for a LIMIT one, and one without. I still recommend using an ORM, that will solve your problem in a better way

Comment: @RiggsFolly The reason I want the LIMIT and OFFSET clauses in there is because Selecting * from Project will return around 20,000 results.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Select all records using MySQL LIMIT and OFFSET query](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15950871/select-all-records-using-mysql-limit-and-offset-query)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turn your thinking around.

```
$values = [
    ':limit' => $this->limit,
    ':offset' => $this->offset
];

const QUERY = "SELECT * FROM Project";
const LIMIT = " LIMIT :limit OFFSET :offset";

$query = QUERY;

if ( isset($values[':limit']) ) {
   $query .= LIMIT;
}

// now do parameter substitution, 
// testing again if you need to add the limit params
```

Comment: That actually makes a lot of sense, fantastic I'll give it a go!

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to solve this in your PHP code, so that you don't use the keyword LIMIT when you don't use limit. If you really want to use the keyword LIMIT and still specify to show all rows, the mysql documentation state:

> To retrieve all rows from a certain offset up to the end of the result set, you can use some large number for the second parameter. This statement retrieves all rows from the 96th row to the last:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl LIMIT 95,18446744073709551615;
```

So the solution is to just use a really big number (the max value of a bigint). Yes I know.. MySQL is terrible.

Comment: Ah, thanks anyway - I'd rather add some further business logic than use that constant :D

Comment: Good :) its indeed nicer to solve it with business logic

Comment: This answer looks strangely like [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15950977/2310830) naughty naughty

Comment: Maybe because it is a quote from the mysql documentation?