# WooCommerce-mysql - get list of products in a category

Tags: php, woocommerce, woocommerce-rest-api

I want to retrieve all products in side a subcategory . this is the code I've  :

```
SELECT * from `wp_term_relationships` where term_taxonomy_id=$subcatId and 
object_id in(select ID from `wp_posts` where  `post_type`='product' and post_status='publish' and ID=wp_term_relationships.object_id)
```

the problem is , this code return about 20 products but when I go to that category in website ,it returns about 40 products.

could you help me ? I need a code to return a list of products inside a category .

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * from `wp_term_relationships` where term_taxonomy_id=$subcatId and object_id in(select ID from `wp_posts` where `post_type`='product' and post_status='publish' and ID=wp_term_relationships.object_id) LIMIT 0,15000000
```

Use Limit keyword in your mysql query.

Limit accepts start and end value.

if you are giving `Limit 5` it will display only top 5 records.
If you are giving `Limit 5,10`  it will display records between 5-10.
If you are giving Limit 0,big number (eg. `Limit 0,100000000`) it will display all the records upto 100000000.

[Select all records using MySQL LIMIT and OFFSET query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15950871/select-all-records-using-mysql-limit-and-offset-query)